# jQuery doesn't work on elements echoed via PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html-table

What I have is a PHP code that generates a html table from mysql database, and then I'm trying to use a jQuery addon that makes the table sortable. I've had this problem many times and can't seem to find a solution anywhere... why doesn't jQuery (or is it Javascript period?) work on a PHP output? Isn't there a way around this?

Here's the code:

```
<html><head>
<title>MySQL Table Viewer</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://tablesorter.com/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://tablesorter.com/addons/pager/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    $("#mytable").tablesorter(); 
} 
); 
</script>
</head><body>
<?php
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pwd = 'lptm42b';

$database = 'sphinx';
$table = 'spheres';

if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
die("Can't connect to database");

if (!mysql_select_db($database))
die("Can't select database");

// sending query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table}");
if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);

echo "<h1>Table: {$table}</h1>";
echo "<table id=\"mytable\" border='1'><tr>";
// printing table headers
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
{
    $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
    echo "<td>{$field->name}</td>";
}
echo "</tr>\n";
// printing table rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";

    // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
    // of $row to $cell variable
    foreach($row as $cell)
        echo "<td>$cell</td>";

    echo "</tr>\n";
}
mysql_free_result($result);
?></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Output is:

```
<html><head>

<script src="../js/jquery_plugin.tablesorter.min.js"></script>

<script src="../js/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>

<script src="../js/jquery_plugin.tablesorter.pager.js"></script>

<title>MySQL Table Viewer</title></head><body>

<h1>Table: lobby</h1><table id="mytable" border='1'><thead><tr><td>tableid</td>    <td>name</td><td>datecreated</td><td>active</td></tr></thead> 
<tbody><tr><td>12341231241</td><td>Oyunum1</td><td>2011-05-09 14:26:51</td><td>0</td>    </tr> 
<tr><td>6677768</td><td>m2</td><td>2011-05-05 14:26:39</td><td>1</td></tr> 
<tr><td>ddf1</td><td>m3</td><td>2011-05-09 14:27:19</td><td>0</td></tr> 
<tr><td>7856844444</td><td>m4</td><td>2011-05-09 14:27:31</td><td>0</td></tr> 
<tr><td>xxxxde4rfd</td><td>m5</td><td>2011-05-09 14:27:43</td><td>0</td></tr> 
</tbody></table>

</body></html>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() 

{ 

    $("#mytable").tablesorter(); 

} 

); 

</script>
```

UPDATE: For some reason syntax coloring is lost at  the end / script> tag in chrome view source

Comment: does it give an error? what browser are you using?

Comment: Don't `echo` HTML. And: `echo "<table id="mytable" border='1'><tr>";
` should throw a syntax error. You can see at the code highlighting that there is a quotation problem.

Comment: You forgot to close your `<table>`.

Comment: doesn't give an error, just doesn't act like the table id doesn't exist- but it does (as i mentioned it exists in the actual code)

Comment: It is still wrong. What you are doing is echoing the string `"<table id="` then there is some undefined constant `mytable` and another string `" border='1'><tr>"`.

Comment: All PHP processing is done before JavaScript even starts to process.  The client-side doesn't have a clue what scripting is being used to create output.

Comment: closed the table still doesn't work

Comment: @Able: How is this related to the problem at hand?

Comment: felix, you are talking about the \"mytable\" fix right?

Comment: Your script tag is not in side the `<html></html>` tag. Put it inside the `head`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Javascript is a client-side technology, meaning to get it work with elements generated directly by the server through php, there are some gymnastics involved.

Try to read up on the [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function in PHP and ajax calls in general.

Also, you might be interested in the .delegate() jQuery method.

Comment: Not true.  Javascript works on DOM elements.  Doesn't matter if the DOM elements are echoed by PHP, Response.Write'd by ASP or what.  If the html elements are there, javascript can be used to interact with that html.  I think the issue here is WHEN the html is written out to the client.

Answer (score 1):

[tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) plugin requires THEAD and TBODY tags in table for it to work

Comment: added those tags, still doesn't work.. why that might be? I've added the output

Comment: @Logan: A header should have TH tags for the header labels instead of TD. Try replacing these, it just might work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't gave a `#mytable` element.

You need to use a selector that matches an element that actually *exists*.

**EDIT**: Your PHP has mis-nested quotes, so the ID isn't actually in the string.
Look at the page source.

Comment: sorry it is a typo i copy pasted it differently

Answer (score 0):

you should add the ID for the table with "mytable" .

Also alsways put thead, tbody in table tags for better output while using JQuery.

Comment: *Also alsways put thead, tbody in table tags for better output while using JQuery.* Why?

Answer (score 0):

Late coming to this party, but you need to know that document.ready won't pick up dynamically generated html if that html is generated AFTER the dom is loaded initially.  There are jQuery plugins to work around this (liveQuery is one of them), but the Document.Ready event fires once per page load, and if the PHP that generates the html is fired AFTER that, then the tablesorter method you call has nothing to sort.