# Why does this jQuery not affect elements outputted from PHP, only ones defined in HTML?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dom, html-lists

I'm trying to make a dynamic nav menu similar to [this](http://cssmenumaker.com/menu/responsive-flat-menu). The javascript is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ne3a90fk/) and worked perfectly when I tested it with:

```
<div id='nav'>
        <ul>
            <li class="navHeader">OOC</li>
            <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
            <li class='active'><a href='#'>Products</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href='#'>Product 1</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                            <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li><a href='#'>Product 2</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                            <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

However, I tried to switch the content of the nav to this:

```
<div id='nav'>
        <ul>
            <li class="navHeader">OOC</li>
            <?php echo getNav(); ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

PHP:

```
function formatNav($navPg){
    $navLine = "<li><a href='?pg=".$navPg['url']."'>".$navPg['name']."</a></li>";
    if ($navPg['subPgs'] > 0) {
        $navLine .= "<ul>";
        foreach($navPg['subPgs'] as $subPg) {
            $navLine .= formatNav($subPg);
        }
        $navLine .= "</ul>";
    }
    return $navLine;
}

function getNav(){
        $navPgs = array(array(
                            'name'=>'profile',
                            'url'=>'profile',
                            'subPgs'=>array(
                                array(
                                    'name'=>'subaccounts',
                                    'url'=>'profile&cat=subs',
                                    'subPgs'=>''
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'name'=>'options',
                                    'url'=>'profile&cat=opts',
                                    'subPgs'=>''
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    );

    $finalNav = "";
    foreach($navPgs as $navPg){
        $finalNav .= formatNav($navPg);
    }
    return $finalNav;
}
```

And none of the Javascript runs on it.

The JS doesn't add the class `has-sub` to the `li` elements that have submenus. Elements with `has-sub` added in the PHP display their CSS properly but don't perform the dropdown event. I debugged the list of `<ul>` elements found after `cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub');` in the JS, and it doesn't include the PHP-generated ones.

I debugged the PHP output, and it's a perfect set of li and ul elements as if I'd formatted them by hand. The JS works fine by itself, the PHP works fine by itself, but when I try to combine them, the JS fails.

Somebody had [the same problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936390/jquery-doesnt-work-on-elements-echoed-via-php), but the answers aren't helpful. I can change my implementation to build the list elements dynamically in javascript based on a JSON list of qualities about it, but I want to know *why* I have to do that instead of echoing them out from PHP directly, especially if there's a more direct workaround.

Is the PHP running after `$(document).ready` fires somehow even though it runs server-side?

JS runs client-side, but valid DOM elements outputted from server-side scripts should be indistinguishable from ones created client-side. Right?

Why isn't this?

edit: Pictures of output from the PHP by itself. Nothing seems wrong with it.
[image]

[image]

Comment: `And none of the Javascript runs on it.` ? which one? i dont see any in OP

Comment: It's at the top in a jsfiddle... As an example, `cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub')` should be able to add that class to any submenu parent.

Comment: The function is not generating the same structure.

Comment: add all relevant code in the OP not in an external link. links rot and it may not help future readers

Comment: Check generated HTML one more time...UL's are not inside LI's, as in your test HTML... You should close ul submenus inside li tags

Comment: Your PHP code doesn't wrap the submenu's `<ul>` in the Profile `<li>`; https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/437r3k1x/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is not generating the same structure, which could be the issue.

I've tweaked your function to return the same structure, as your *working* one.

Give it a try.

```
<?php
function formatNav($navPg){
    $navLine = "<li><a href='".$navPg['url']."'>".$navPg['name']."</a>";
    if (is_array($navPg['subPgs']) && count($navPg['subPgs']) > 0) {
        $navLine .= "<ul>";
        foreach($navPg['subPgs'] as $subPg) {
            $navLine .= formatNav($subPg);
        }
        $navLine .= "</ul>";
    } else {
        $navLine .= "</li>";
    }
    if (is_array($navPg['subPgs']) && count($navPg['subPgs']) > 0) {
        $navLine .= "</li>";
    }
    return $navLine;
}

function getNav(){
    $navPgs = array(
        array(
            'name'=>'Home',
            'url'=>'#',
            'subPgs'=>array()
        ),
        array(
            'name'=>'Products',
            'url'=>'#',
            'subPgs'=>array(
                array(
                    'name'=>'Product 1',
                    'url'=>'#',
                    'subPgs'=>array(
                        array(
                            'name'=>'Sub Product',
                            'url'=>'#',
                            'subPgs'=>array()
                        ),array(
                            'name'=>'Sub Product',
                            'url'=>'#',
                            'subPgs'=>array()
                        ),
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'name'=>'Product 2',
                    'url'=>'#',
                    'subPgs'=>array(
                        array(
                            'name'=>'Sub Product',
                            'url'=>'#',
                            'subPgs'=>array()
                        ),array(
                            'name'=>'Sub Product',
                            'url'=>'#',
                            'subPgs'=>array()
                        ),
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );

    $finalNav = "";
    foreach($navPgs as $navPg){
        $finalNav .= formatNav($navPg);
    }
    return $finalNav;
}
```

https://3v4l.org/gjM0Y

```
<div id='nav'>
   <ul>
      <li class="navHeader">OOC</li>
      <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
      <li>
         <a href='#'>Products</a>
         <ul>
            <li>
               <a href='#'>Product 1</a>
               <ul>
                  <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                  <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href='#'>Product 2</a>
               <ul>
                  <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                  <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Haha, just got done writing out the same fix. Works beautifully now. Thanks for taking the time to do this. I feel like this title's misleading now...should be more like "what happens if you don't double-check your output?".

Comment: np, glad to help.